# How do I install Python Versions 3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9,3.10 on OpenSuse 15.4/15.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, repository, opensuse, suse

I need to install all 5 Python versions from 3.6 to 3.10 on 6 different linux OSes.
For Ubuntu, I'm doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

# Installing all the required Python Versions
sudo apt-get install python3.6 python3.7 python3.8 python3.9 python3.10 -y
```

and it's working fine.
For RHEL and Suse, I was doing this:

```
versions=("3.6.15" "3.7.12" "3.8.12" "3.9.7" "3.10.0")

# Install each version using a for loop
for version in "${versions[@]}"
do
    # Download source code
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/Python-$version.tgz
    tar -xf Python-$version.tgz
    cd Python-$version

    # Configure and install
    ./configure --enable-optimizations
    make -j 4
    sudo make altinstall
```

this is working on RHEL, but not working on Suse.
Why is it not working on SUSE, and what's the alternative that I can use?

```
sudo zypper ar obs://python/python:3.7 python37
sudo zypper in python37
```

zypper install is giving me this Error:
[image]

Comment: Try pyenv, and consider using that for every OS.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why it's not working for you, but,

Try this alternate method:
sudo zypper ar -f obs://devel:languages:python/python devel_python
sudo zypper ref
sudo zypper in python37

Comment: Getting the error "Repository is invalid - Valid metadata not found at specified URL"
while running zypper ref

Comment: oh sheesh, why would that be?!